# What's the difference between using a bound service and a just a reference to a service?

Tags: java, android, service

From reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798663/11347922 I was able to understand a little more about the purpose of the Binder class. From what I read is really helpful when we want to expose some of our application's functionality to other applications through interprocess communication (IPC).
However why using a bound service and IBinder interface when you want to interact with the service from activities and other components in your own application?
Couldn't this be achieved by passing a Service reference?

I am going to make an example:

```
public class MyService extends Service{

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {+
new MyThread(MyService.this).start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public Foo<?> getSomething(){
return ...;
}

}


public class MyThread extends Thread{

private MyService myService;

public MyThread(MyService myService){
this.myService = myService;
}


public void run()
{
...
myService.getSomething();
}

}
```

Maybe the only reason to use a bound service it for an internal purpose it's just because the service would get destroyed when there are no components bound to it?